# Is UILocalNotification cancelled when the application is closed?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I created UILocalNotification then I scheduled many notifications. Will these scheduled notifications be cancelled if the app is closed?

If it will be cancelled, do I have to schedule them every time on application load?

Comment: That will not be cancelled, but your app will not run until the user starts it.

Answer (score 3):

No, the entire purpose of notifications is to notify users of certain events when an app is not currently running.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, the `UILocalNotifications` are taken over by the OS once they are scheduled, so they will go off even if the have has been quit and deleted from the "background running mode."

So no, you will not need to reschedule them on application start, unless you want to schedule more.

The complete guide for `UILocalNotifications`can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).